# how to make UITextView height dynamic according to text length?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

As you can see in this image

the `UITextView` changes it's height according to the text length, I want to make it adjust it's height according to the text length.

***I saw other questions, but solutions there didn't work for me**

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

Comment: I use nextGrowingTextView https://github.com/muukii/NextGrowingTextView I've even written an implementation in Objective c https://github.com/mcmatan/NextGrowingInternalTextViewObjectiveC

Comment: CSGrowingTextView is also an alternative for this problem: https://github.com/cloverstudio/CSGrowingTextView

Comment: make sure you set the hugging and compression resistance priority to less

Comment: these days it is **COMPLETELY AUTOMATIC** - don't forget to disable scrolling.  obviously you need correct constraints all around the view (as any view)

Comment: no it's not, Fattie. I mean it surely is if you use native fonts, but the moment you import another font - here you go, you have this issue.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

this **Works** for me, all other solutions didn't.

```
func adjustUITextViewHeight(arg : UITextView) {
    arg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    arg.sizeToFit()
    arg.scrollEnabled = false
}
```

In Swift 4 the syntax of `arg.scrollEnabled = false` has changed to `arg.isScrollEnabled = false`.

Comment: When there is a huge text then text is not displaying when I make false to `scrollEnabled` property. Can you Please help me with that. ? I mean text is there but it is not visible.

Comment: please ask a separate question with full code and storyboards details.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen +1, it works and also I've tried with static tableview cell, excellent :)

Comment: and make sure to set these properties after setting the .text ;) . Thanks!

Comment: for my case only arg.sizeToFit() is enough. arg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints removed my constrains

Comment: thank you @NiibFouda, you have saved my day only the arg.sizeToFit() was suffisant

Comment: @WalidSassi you are welcome friend 

Answer (score 88):

In Storyboard / Interface Builder simply disable scrolling in the Attribute inspector.

In code `textField.scrollEnabled = false` should do the trick.

Comment: I can not believe it's that simple. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Explanation of why this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65861960/815742

Answer (score 52):

All I had to do was:

1. Set the constraints to the **top, left, and right** of the textView.
2. **Disable scrolling** in Storyboard.

This allows autolayout to dynamically size the textView based on its content.

Comment: Neat and Clean!! Thanks +1

Comment: this isn't gonna work while you editing the text.

Answer (score 29):

Give this a try:

```
CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
self.textView.frame = frame;
```

Edit- Here's the Swift:

```
var frame = self.textView.frame
frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height
self.textView.frame = frame
```

Comment: ok, thanks, i will try this one too, and tell you the result.

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 4**

Add It To Your Class

`UITextViewDelegate`

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
      let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
      textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
      let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
      var newFrame = textView.frame
      newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
      textView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: It worked well as my need.But textview keyboard is not opening from second Time onwards except for first line..can anybody help me.

Comment: `textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` is also needed

Comment: just call sizeToFit() when textview resigns first responder.

Answer (score 15):

Followed by DeyaEldeen's answer. 
In my case. I grow the textview height automatically by adding

swift 3

`textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 textView.isScrollEnabled = false`

Comment: In my case use textView.scrollEnabled = false; and it worked

Comment: This works for my case as well.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5**, Use extension:

```
extension UITextView {
    func adjustUITextViewHeight() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.sizeToFit()
        self.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Usecase:

```
textView.adjustUITextViewHeight()
```

And don't care about the height of texeView in the storyboard (just use a constant at first)

Answer (score 10):

**I added these two lines of code and work fine for me.**

Works in Swift 5+

```
func adjustUITextViewHeight(textView : UITextView)
{
     textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
     textView.isScrollEnabled = false
     textView.sizeToFit()
}
```

Comment: simple, no library needed

Answer (score 9):

just make a connection with your textView's height Constraint

```
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and use this code below

```
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Value of type 'UITextField' has no member 'contentSize'

Comment: @AnantaPrasad its UITextView not UItextField check above connections

Answer (score 9):

If your `textView` is allowed to grow as tall as the content, then

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

should just work with autolayout.

If you want to remain the `textView` to be scrollable, you need to add an optional height constraint,

```
internal lazy var textViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
  let constraint = self.textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
  constraint.priority = .defaultHigh
  return constraint
}()

public override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()

  // Assuming there is width constraint setup on the textView.
  let targetSize = CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
  textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.sizeThatFits(targetSize).height
}
```

The reason to override `layoutSubviews()` is to make sure the textView is laid out properly horizontally so we can rely on the width to calculate the height.

Since the height constraint is set to a lower priority, if it runs out space vertically the actual height of the `textView` will be less than the `contentSize`. And the textView will be scrollable.

Answer (score 7):

This answer may be late but I hope it helps someone.

For me, these 2 lines of code worked:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
textView.sizeToFit()
```

But don't set height constraint for your **Textview**

Comment: and don't put textView inside StackView, I havn't managed to get it work so

Answer (score 5):

it's straight forward to do in programatic way. just follow these steps

1. add an observer to content length of textfield

   ```
   [yourTextViewObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
   ```
2. implement observer

   ```
   -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
   UITextView *tv = object;

       //Center vertical alignment
       CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
       topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
       tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};


       mTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = tv.contentSize.height;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

           [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
       }];

   }
   ```
3. if you want to stop textviewHeight to increase after some time during typing then implement this and set textview delegate to self.

   ```
   -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
   {
       if(range.length + range.location > textView.text.length)
       {
           return NO;
       }

       NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;

       return (newLength > 100) ? NO : YES;

   }
   ```

Comment: this is obj-c, I use swift.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen oops , plz write respective code ..  :)

Comment: i added the swift tag in the question, so it's all about swift.

Comment: for perfect for Obj-C.Thanks For it :)

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4+**

This is extremely easy with **autolayout**! I'll explain the most simple use case. Let's say there is only a `UITextView` in your `UITableViewCell`.

- Fit the `textView` to the `contentView` with constraints.
- Disable scrolling for the `textView`.
- Update the `tableView` on `textViewDidChange`.

That's all!

```
protocol TextViewUpdateProtocol {
    func textViewChanged()
}

class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    //MARK: Reuse ID
    static let identifier = debugDescription()
    
    //MARK: UI Element(s)
    /// Reference of the parent table view so that it can be updated
    var textViewUpdateDelegate: TextViewUpdateProtocol!
    
    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()
    
    //MARK: Padding Variable(s)
    let padding: CGFloat = 50
    
    //MARK: Initializer(s)
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubviews()
        addConstraints()
        
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    //MARK: Helper Method(s)
    func addSubviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(textView)
    }
    
    func addConstraints() {
        textView.leadingAnchor  .constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor .constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor      .constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor   .constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}

extension TextViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewUpdateDelegate.textViewChanged()
    }
    
}
```

Now you have to inherit implement the protocol in your `ViewController`.

```
extension ViewController: TextViewUpdateProtocol {
    
    func textViewChanged() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
}
```

Check out my [repo](https://github.com/rakeshashastri/resizing-textView-in-tableviewcell) for the full implementation.

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT 4

Change the size when typing

UITextViewDelegate

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        yourTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        yourTextView.sizeToFit()
        yourTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

        let calHeight = yourTextView.frame.size.height
        yourTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 193, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 32, height: calHeight)
    }
```

Change the size when load

```
func textViewNotasChange(arg : UITextView) {
        arg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        arg.sizeToFit()
        arg.isScrollEnabled = false

        let calHeight = arg.frame.size.height
        arg.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 40, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 32, height: calHeight)
    }
```

Call the function of the second option like this:

```
textViewNotasChange(arg: yourTextView)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my project, the view controller is involved with lots of Constraints and StackView, and I set the TextView height as a constraint, and it varies based on the textView.contentSize.height value.

step1: get a IB outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

step2: use the delegation method below.

```
extension NewPostViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
     func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
          textViewHeight.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height + 10
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better yet **swift 4** add as an extension:

```
extension UITextView {
    func resizeForHeight(){
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.sizeToFit()
        self.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its working

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textviewconclusion.frame.size.width
    textviewconclusion.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textviewconclusion.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textviewconclusion.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textviewconclusion.frame = newFrame
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 Add an observer to the content length of textfield

```
   yourTextView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: (NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new), context: nil);
```

2 Implement observer

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        let tv = object as! UITextView;
        var topCorrect = (tv.bounds.size.height - tv.contentSize.height * tv.zoomScale)/2.0;
        topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
        tv.contentOffset.x = 0;
        tv.contentOffset.y = -topCorrect;
        self.yourTextView.contentSize.height = tv.contentSize.height;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two pitfalls in iOS 8.3 when coming with `textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10`

Refer to my [gist](https://gist.github.com/acalism/11ed8c865d4f58df8494ee999598490c), please.

```
textView.attributedText = originalContent

let lineLimit = 10
textView.isEditable = true
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
textView.textContainerInset = .zero // default is (8, 0, 8, 0)
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = lineLimit // Important condition
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

// two incomplete methods, which do NOT work in iOS 8.3

// size.width可能比maxSize.width小 ————遗憾的是 iOS 8.3 上此方法无视maximumNumberOfLines参数，所以得借助于UILabel
// size.width may be less than maxSize.width, ---- Do NOT work in iOS 8.3, which disregards textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines
// let size = textView.sizeThatFits(maxSize) 

// 遗憾的是 iOS 8.3 上此方法失效了，得借助于UILabel
// Does not work in iOS 8.3
// let size = textView.layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textView.textContainer).size 

// Suggested method: use a temperary label to get its size
let label = UILabel(); label.attributedText = originalContent
let size = label.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: maxSize), limitedToNumberOfLines: lineLimit).size
textView.frame.size = size
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration here

```
    fileprivate weak var textView: UITextView!
```

Call your setupview here

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         setupViews()
    }
```

Setup here

```
    fileprivate func setupViews() {

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.text = "your text here"
    textView.font = UIFont.poppinsMedium(size: 14)
    textView.textColor = UIColor.brownishGrey
    textView.textAlignment = .left
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)

   self.view.addSubview(textView)

   self.textView = textView

   setupConstraints()

   }
```

Setup constraints here

```
   fileprivate func setupConstraints() {

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20),
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 150),
        ])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to resize the textview according to the inside content size, like in messageing app.
Use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GrowingTextView)(GrowingTextView), it will make your life easier, than coding the dynamic resizing of textview on your own.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put textView in StackView
2. Set constraints(top, bottom, left, right) for stackView
3. Add height constraint to StackView, select this constraint and set it 'Greater Than or Equal' in Relation, on the right panel

Answer (score 0):

if you want preload `textView` on controller load. Call this function from view `didload()`:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {   
    let esmitated = CGSize(width: txtView.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let esmitatedSize = txtView.sizeThatFits(esmitated)
    self.heghtConstraint.constant = esmitatedSize.height
}
```