# Self sizing uitextview till specific height

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have an app which has chatting functionality where `UITextview` is used for entering the message. `UITextview` height has to be dynamic (if user enters the message, the height has to be changed according to the text length till a specific Height).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714829/7084910 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jb29c22xu8 will help you

Comment: you can use contentsize property.

Comment: This is the link to answer you looking for try it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Comment: thanks for the comments one more doubt. After 5 or 6 line textview have to do its original functionality i.e (constant height after 5 or 6 line and do scrolling )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disable Scrolling of textView.

[image]

[image]

***TO Increase Height to a specific value and then enable scrolling.***

**Provide a maximum height constraint** then add this code to your viewController

```
 class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
    {
        @IBOutlet weak var yourTextView: UITextView!

        let textViewMaxHeight: CGFloat = 100
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            yourTextView.delegate = self
        }

        func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)
        {
            if textView.contentSize.height >= self.textViewMaxHeight
            {
                textView.scrollEnabled = true
            }
            else
                {
                textView.frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
                textView.scrollEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question. Disabling will only result in fixing the viewable text area height.

Comment: how can i stop after 4 lines (textview have to do its original functionality after 4 lines)

Comment: @midhunnarayan Did u mean that up to 4 lines it should increase height and after that, it should enable scrolling ??

Comment: @Anuraj yes exactly

Comment: @Anuraj tried but in my case  after this condition (textView.contentSize.height >= self.textViewMaxHeight) textview height becoming 0 view is not showing

Comment: @MidhunNarayan Have u set Max height constraint to TextView??

Answer (score 7):

Add a height constraint to your textView and create an outlet so you can adjust it. Then you can use the UITexfield delegate method textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) to adjust the height.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    // get the current height of your text from the content size
    var height = textView.contentSize.height

    // clamp your height to desired values
    if height > 90 {
        height = 90
    } else if height < 50 {
        height = 50
    }

    // update the constraint
    textViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

shorter version...

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 90.0
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 50.0
    textViewHeightConstraint.constant = min(maxHeight, max(minHeight, textView.contentSize.height))           
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: make sure to set your controller as delegate of the textView. textView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad or set it up in the storyboard.

Comment: also no other constraints should limit the height of yout textView. vertically it should be pinned only at the bottom and get its height from the height constraint.

Comment: After maxheight if I enter text its not displaying

Comment: make sure to leave scrolling enabled for the textview. it should scroll after max height.

Comment: best answer to this question

Answer (score 4):

In case you are subclassing UITextView this could be a solution as well:

```
class Message: UITextView {


    var maximalSizeNotScrollable: CGFloat = 200
    var minimumHeightTextView: CGFloat = 35

    var textViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {

            if textViewHeightAnchor != nil {
                textViewHeightAnchor.isActive = false

            }
            textViewHeightAnchor = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: min(maximalSizeNotScrollable, max(minimumHeightTextView, contentSize.height)))
            textViewHeightAnchor.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

            textViewHeightAnchor.isActive = true
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

The priority needs to be smaller than 1000 otherwise you will encounter problems with _UITemporaryLayoutHeight.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same problem. After reading @Anuraj's response, I dragged and dropped the height constraint of the UITextView to view controller because when textview reaches to the max height and when the scroll is enabled textview was getting smaller just to display one line, so I found the solution by giving the max height to the height constraint of textview. Textview will expand until it reaches max height, after that it will be scrollable. When you delete text, textview height will get smaller automatically.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txMessageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!    
let textViewMaxHeight: CGFloat = 120

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.contentSize.height >= self.textViewMaxHeight{
        txMessageHeight.constant = self.textViewMaxHeight
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }else{
        textView.frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Height Constraint of the TextView to <= 120(maxHeight) in StoryBoard

[image]

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.contentSize.height >= maxHeight {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

And if you want to reset the height of TextView when its empty, you can just write

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

---