# How to Observer UITexFiled startEditing and EndEditing in its SubClass?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to observer in `UITexFiled` sub class ,if current textField is started Ending or Ended Editing in same class .

if I'll write `self.delegate = self` then my `ViewController` `UITextField` method will not called .

I want to make a `UITexFiled` `SubClass` when every editing is started then I'll scale up the textFiled ,and when editing is done then `UITexField` will be back to normal size . but I want to handle from my subclass not to write logic every `UITexFeildDelegate` in all `ViewController` Please help me .

Comment: I used a UITextView:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568664/8887336

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self sizing uitextview till specific height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622024/self-sizing-uitextview-till-specific-height)

Comment: This Question  is not duplicate,I got the below answer  @PaFi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add targets for the specific events

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didBegin), for: .editingDidBegin)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEnd), for: .editingDidEnd)
    }
    @objc func didBegin() {

    }
    @objc func didEnd() {

    }
}
```