# Text is not appearing when UITextView's content is more?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uitextview

I don't need to scroll inside a UITextView so disabling a scrolling property of my UITextView.
It means UITextView's height is dynamic base on his content.

**When I added more text in UITextView then text is not appearing.**
It is working with less content.

As per my observation if height of UITextView **exceeds 8100** then it stops rendering but not sure about it.

[image]

**here is a structure of storyboard.**

Comment: **It means UITextView's height is dynamic base on his content.** -> What code you have written for this

Comment: I just assign a more text. 
txtDummyTextView.text = """ Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 15...."""

Comment: It  will not automatically increase height of your textview or because of issue of constraint .  You have to adjust height of your textview(i.e height constraint constant) according to text size. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714272/how-to-make-uitextview-height-dynamic-according-to-text-length

Comment: you can used third party lib  like [Growing Text Field](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Will provide you demo app.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Here is mine code. https://github.com/urvishagile/TextViewDemo

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and please check below sample, i am modify your sample. This is working in my case.

Refer:- [Updated Demo](https://github.com/dhavalagile/TextViewDemo)