# How to resize UITextView while typing inside it in collection view cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new in swift and I am not able to resize the size of textview in collection view cell. I need to resize the height of textview as well as collection view cell height at the same time while editing. My code is like this

```
class TimeSheetCollectionViewCell1: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var txtviewTimeSheet: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var btnDelete: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var txtviewTimeSheetHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        txtviewTimeSheet.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        txtviewTimeSheet.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7810397744, green: 0.7810582519, blue: 0.7810482979, alpha: 1)
        txtviewTimeSheet.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        txtviewTimeSheet.autocorrectionType = .no
        let iconUniChar: UniChar = 0xf057
        btnDelete.setTitle(String(format: "%C", iconUniChar), for: .normal)
        btnDelete.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    }
}

extension TimeSheetViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrcheck.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TimeSheetCollectionViewCell1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TimeSheetCollectionViewCell1
        cell.txtviewTimeSheet.text = arrcheck[indexPath.row]
        cell.txtviewTimeSheet.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))
        cell.btnDelete.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnDeleteClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        cell.txtviewTimeSheet.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let label = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text = arrcheck[indexPath.item]
        label.sizeToFit()
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width/1) - 10, height: label.frame.height)
    }
    
    @objc func btnDeleteClick(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        print("buttonPressed ! \(sender.tag)")
        arrcheck.remove(at: sender.tag)
        CollectionViewTimeSheet.reloadData()
    }
    @objc func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Done")
        print("Text Field = ",textFieldIndexPath)
        print("Text Filed Row = ",textFieldIndexPath.row)
        print("Text Filed Section = ",textFieldIndexPath.section)
        print(arrcheck[textFieldIndexPath.row])
        print("Arr = ",arrcheck)
        CollectionViewTimeSheet.reloadData()
    }
}

class TimeSheetViewController: UIViewController ,UITextViewDelegate{
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell = textView.superview?.superview as! UICollectionViewCell
        let table: UICollectionView = cell.superview as! UICollectionView
        textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)!
        print("Text Field = ",textFieldIndexPath)
        print(textView.text as Any)
        arrcheck[textFieldIndexPath.row] = textView.text!
    }
}
```

I need to resize textview and collection view cell.Is it possible? If it is possible please share some code. Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: Why are you using textview in collectionview cell?

Comment: use a label instead of textView

Comment: @VedSharma Yes I am using textview in collectionview cell

Comment: My question is why are you using textview in collectionview cell? what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AwaisMobeen User has to type into the text how can user type into label. thats why I can't

Comment: @VedSharma I am using textview so that user can type in it

Comment: @Muju That's obvious that you are using it so the user can type on it. But my question is why inside collectionview? can you show me what you want to achieve?

Comment: @VedSharma Please see I attached Image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714272/how-to-make-uitextview-height-dynamic-according-to-text-length Please have a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827126/change-the-uitableviewcell-height-according-to-amount-of-text

Comment: @AwaisMobeen Check this already not helped